# unable to pass complex objects to webapi from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using below code to post data to webapi controller but complex data objects are coming as null in the API controller.However, if i pass object at a time i'm seeing results meaning it is sending over the flat objects but not complex objects.Can anyone please guide me what wrong i'm doing here or is there any other way to do this??

below are the data objects and code snippet that i'm using:
Models:

var portfolio={
Accounts:{accountnumber:'',
          SSN:'',
          ..almost 15 fields in this object},
Investments:{ID:'',
             totalamount:'',
             etc..here also we have more than 10 objects}

Foo: {F1:'',F2:'',F3:''...}

Foo1: {F11:'',F12:'',F13:''...}

}

Angular service:

```
var get=funtion(portfolio){
            return  $http.post('/api/values',
                JSON.stringify(portfolio),
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            )
}
```

webapi controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public User Post([Frombody]portfolio model)
    {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json is the `http.post()` default content type, so there is no need to neither specify that, nor stringify you object.
Assuming you are posting a valid json object, this should suffice:

```
var get = funtion(portfolio){
  return  $http.post('/api/values', portfolio); 
}
```

Comment: Oh..good to know but for some reason it was not working but i was able to accept parameter as Jobject and convert them to classes.